# Why aren't Xtick labels aligning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a group by object but the x axis labels are not aligning. Any help? Thanks.

My code:

```py
gdp_by_region.plot(kind='bar', align= 'center')
plt.xticks(fontsize= 'small')

plt.show()
```

Outcome:

[image: plot pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose the labels themselves are well aligned, but you will have a lot of whitespaces in your labels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ticks = ["    AAA    ", 
         "BB         ",
         "   CCCCCCCC",
         "  DDD      "]
y = [3,4,5,4]

plt.figure(figsize=(3,3))
plt.plot(ticks, y)
plt.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I knew it was going to be something dumb like that. Thank you.